# DirectX Render to texture, accesing data in pixel shader

Tags: directx, directx-11

How can i access my data in shader from shader resource view.?

Is there any need for projection vector for accessing data in shader, which was rendered to a texture?

Edit 1:

I am performing following task:

```
d3d11Device->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, NULL, &renderTargetTextureMap);

d3d11Device->CreateRenderTargetView(renderTargetTextureMap, &renderTargetViewDesc, &renderTargetViewMap);


d3d11Device->CreateShaderResourceView(renderTargetTextureMap, &shaderResourceViewDesc, &shaderResourceViewMap);


d3d11DevCon->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &shaderResourceViewMap);
```

But in my pixel shader mapping is not correct of the texture and destination pixel, any idea..?

I need for this issue:

[DirectX 11 Render to Texture Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46606680/directx-11-render-to-texture-issue)

Comment: if you pass your texture using deviceContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &texture); then you can sample it in pixel shader and access element using shaderTexture.Sample(SampleType, input.tex);

Comment: I am performing following task:

d3d11Device->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, NULL, &renderTargetTextureMap);

d3d11Device->CreateRenderTargetView(renderTargetTextureMap, &renderTargetViewDesc, &renderTargetViewMap);


d3d11Device->CreateShaderResourceView(renderTargetTextureMap, &shaderResourceViewDesc, &shaderResourceViewMap);


d3d11DevCon->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &shaderResourceViewMap);

Comment: Have you gone through this tutorial: http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut22.html?

Comment: Yes, it is also using shader resource view like mine,

since it is showing a cube rotation and all so many projection matrices are der, do i also need to use projection matrix here.?

Comment: @AkshitVerma first download that sample and study the code

Comment: I don't really understand the question. If this is the question "How can i access my data in shader from shader resource view?" then you already have the answer in the first comment, you need to sample from that resource.